# Postgres Epoch timestamp data type number of digits

Tags: postgresql, epoch

I am creating an Epoch timestamp, which is said to be double precision format.

I saved this to my local DB, and am using it to sync items to clients.

I have now been confronted with some situations, that the timestamp will only show 5 digits, eg. 1645604141.22873,

since according to Postgres docu (The to_timestamp function can also take a single double precision argument to convert from Unix epoch to timestamp with time zone. ), the double precision has 15 digits

double precision    8 bytes variable-precision, inexact 15 decimal digits precision

This would mean that the format above would be correct,

BUT I am seeing the Epoch timestamp in my table with 16 digits like this:

1645604141.228735

Does anyone have a good explanation, on how the epoch is really stored, and how it can guarantee my 6 digits after the comma (microsecond)

Comment: Better use the data type `timestamp with time zone` or at least `timestamp`. Why make your life harder by choosing an inappropriate data type?

Comment: 1) What version of Postgres? 2) In `psql` what does `show  extra_float_digits ;` return? 3) You do realize that: "The data types real and double precision are inexact, variable-precision numeric types.", emphasis on inexact? If you want exact numbers stick to `numeric` and if you want to work with timestamps stick with actual `timestamp` types.